# Rewrite code to get only several variables

Tags: java

I have this code which I would like to use to translate keys and return data to front end:

```
@GetMapping("pages")
public Page<ContractDTO> pagxes(@RequestParam(value = "page") int page, @RequestParam(value = "size") int size) {
    return contractService.findAll(page, size)
            //.map(mapper::toDTO);
            .map(g -> new ContractDTO(g.getName(), getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id())));
}

private String getMerchantName(int id) {
    Optional<Merchants> obj = merchantService.findById(id);
    return obj.get().getName();
}
```

DTO :

```
public class ContractDTO {

    private Integer id; 
    .....
    private Integer acquirer_id;    
    private Integer terminal_id;    
    private String merchant_id;
    ......
}
```

How I can rewrite this code `.map(g -> new ContractDTO(g.getName(), getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id())));` to translate from int to String using `getMerchantName(int id)` only terminal_id and merchant_id and all other variables not to be translated?

I can create constructor in ContractDTO but the code will be huge. Is there some other way?

Error:

[image]

The method builder() is undefined for the type ContractDTO

Comment: don't think a lot about huge code, but think for solving the problem with a clean idea, using many DTOs or constructors is not a bad idea, beside some times we use design patterns with many classes to just make the code clean and more maintainable

Comment: Can you show me some solution, please?

Answer (score 1):

In your case because you want to avoid multiple constructors, You can use a [builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), by using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven) library, it can be more easier, so you can just annotate your class of `ContractDTO` with this library annotation, and you have every thing to go :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class ContractDTO {

    private Integer id;  
    private String name;
    private Integer acquirerId;    
    private Integer terminalId;    
    private String merchantId;

}
```

then your code can be :

```
...
.map(g -> ContractDTO.builder()
        .name(g.getName())
        .merchantName(g.getMerchantId())
        .build()
)....
```

Comment: But I get  cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method toBuilder() when I try to compile the code. Probably I need to generate the code first?

Comment: @PeterPenzov did you add the dependency of lombok in your project?

Comment: yes, I did. But looks like ti need more configuration?

Comment: any idea what is missing?

Comment: @PeterPenzov did you import `import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;`?

Comment: Yes I did. I get the error when I call the builder()

Comment: @PeterPenzov yes yes, always I make the same mistake, [the answer of Anurag Dwivedi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55426045/5558072) is the solution

Comment: @PeterPenzov can you show me the erro? make sure to not use new key word just the name of your Object

Comment: @PeterPenzov you have to solve the first problem of `mapper::toDto`, the problem influence the second `map`

Comment: Is there any other solution without lombook?

Comment: Do you have the problem when compiling with Maven from command line ? Do you only have the problem inside your IDE ? If the latter is Eclipse, you have to configure the Annotation processors in order to make Eclipse compile. I think there's also a smilar thing to do with IntelliJ

Comment: @PeterPenzov yes there are but it is a little ugly where you create your builder by your self, so don't lose hope step by step

Comment: @PeterPenzov so follow this https://www.projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse You won't need the annotation processors, I made a confusion with Hibernate Metamodel generator I usually use along lombok in my projects ;)

Comment: I installed lombook but again I get The method builder() is undefined for the type ContractDTO

Comment: Ok, after refresh it's found.

Comment: But when I compile it again I get cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method builder()

Comment: Any idea why javac can't find it?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I will let this an exercice for you, you are Hero so you can search and found what is the problem, have to sleep now sorry ;)