# Configuring lombok for builder

Tags: java, lombok

I want to avoid multiple constructors, so I want to use a [builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), by using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven) library, it can be more easier, so I want to annotate class of `ContractDTO` with this library annotation:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class ContractDTO {

    private Integer id;  
    private String name;
    private Integer acquirerId;    
    private Integer terminalId;    
    private String merchantId;

}
```

then your code can be :

```
...
.map(g -> new ContractDTO().toBuilder()
        .name(g.getName())
        .merchantName(g.getMerchantId())
        .build()
)....
```

But when I try to compile the code I get cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method toBuilder()

Probably I need to generate the code in advance?

Comment: Are you compiling the code in IntelliJ?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `builder()`? toBuilder is to create copying builder from instance.

Comment: I use eclipse for IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
 ContractDTO.builder()
    .name(g.getName())
    .merchantName(g.getMerchantId())
    .build();
```

If we want to create copies or near-copies of objects, we can add the property toBuilder = true to the @Builder annotation. This tells Lombok to add a toBuilder() method to our Class. When we invoke the toBuilder() method, it returns a builder initialized with the properties of the instance it is called on.

Comment: exactly this is the solution, I forgot this way, In fact the OP ask about my mistake in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422753/rewrite-code-to-get-only-several-variables/55424076#55424076), I will change it and +1

Answer (score 0):

By default your IDE cant detect what lombok has generated ,so, to avoid the compilation errors which appear after you added some annotations, i suggest you to install the lombok plugin into your IDE, so you can have your classes generated anc detected by your IDE in real time.